# Когда я пытаюсь установить Андроид Студио на мак м1, у меня вылетает ошибка 404.Что делать?

Tags: android-studio, http-status-code-404, m1

[image: Первое шаг]

[image: Второй шаг]

Я пытаюсь загрузить Android Studio на свой Mac M1 с официального сайта, и после того, как я нажму кнопку «Mac с чипом Apple м1». У меня вылетает ошибка 404 на экране, я попытался перезапустить свой Mac, но ничего не произошло, у меня все еще есть ошибка 404 при попытке скачки . Хочу скачать Андроид Студио для разработки на Flutter Что делать ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the site of the Russian-speaking SO community, please translate your question into Russian.

Comment: Hello,I need to re-post ,my question but on Russian  ?

Comment: You can just edit this question, just click on [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1358964/edit) button at the bottom of the question.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку